# How can an object overwrite itself using setter?

Tags: javascript, class, object, setter, overwrite

I want an object to overwrite itself using a setter. Unfortunately it does not work with my script. Probably it is because "this" cannot stand alone. Is there another way to solve this?

```
class myClass {
  set updateObj(value) {
    this = value // how to overwrite the object itself? "this" doesn't work ..
  }
}

let myObject = new myClass()
const test = (myObject.updateObj = { foo: "bar" })

console.log(test)
```

Comment: are you trying to achieve this? `myObject = { foo: "bar" }`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No an instance cannot replace itself.

But you can *merge* some data with properties into `this` [with `Object.assign`.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign)

```js
class myClass {
  set updateObj(value) {
    Object.assign(this, value)
  }
}

let myObject = new myClass()
myObject.updateObj = { foo: "bar" }
console.log(myObject)

myObject.updateObj = { foo: "baz" }
console.log(myObject)
```